# Como concatenar colunas (em string) com condional, criando uma nova coluna no python?

Tags: python, condição, concatenação-de-string

Boa tarde, pessoal!
Estou precisando unir duas colunas e uma string, utilizando condicionais, em um projeto no Python. Por exemplo: tenho duas colunas ('col_A' e 'col_B') e quero formar uma coluna 'col_C'. Caso a coluna col_B seja 'x', a nova coluna assume como valor 'x'; se a col_B for 'y', a nova coluna assume 'y'; em nenhum dos casos, a nova coluna seria formada por 'col_A' + '/' + 'col_B'. Eu tentei o seguinte código:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
if row['col_B'] == 'x':
    df.loc[index,'col_C'] = 'x'
elif row['col_B'] == 'y':
    df.loc[index,'col_C'] = 'y'
else:
    df.loc[index,'col_C'] = row['col_A'] + '/' + row['col_B']
```

Só que esse método é muito demorado, especialmente quando o dataframe é extenso. Existe algum método mais eficiente?

Answer (score -2):

A solução seria utilizar as condicionais na atribuição:

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_A": ["a", "b", "c"], "col_B": ["x", "y", "z"]})

df
  col_A col_B
0     a     x
1     b     y
2     c     z
```

### Testando coluna B (col_B) para o valor x

```
df.loc[df["col_B"] == "x", "col_C"] = "x"

df
  col_A col_B col_C
0     a     x     x
1     b     y   NaN
2     c     z   NaN
```

### Testando coluna B (col_B) para o valor y

```
df.loc[df["col_B"] == "y", "col_C"] = "y"

df
  col_A col_B col_C
0     a     x     x
1     b     y     y
2     c     z   NaN
```

### Testando coluna B (col_B) quando esta não possui os valores x e y

```
df.loc[(df["col_B"] != "x") & (df["col_B"] != "y"), "col_C"] = df["col_A"] + "/" + df["col_B"]

df
  col_A col_B col_C
0     a     x     x
1     b     y     y
2     c     z   c/z
```

**TODOS** os comandos devem ser executados para ter o resultado final.

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, poderia dizer o motivo para que eu melhore a resposta?